# Add comment in an array of cells with the contents of the comment of each of the cells taken from another array of cells in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm trying to use VBA to make a code that can add comments on cells from D8:F38 in Sheet1 with the contents of comments in each of the cells (D8:F38 cells in Sheet1) are referred from another worksheet in the same workbook.

The contents of reference for the comment of each cells from `D8:F38` in `Sheet1` has to be from the `=COUNTIFS` formula that those cells (`D8:F38` cells in `Sheet1`) initially ran. Is it possible? Or is the criteria too complex for the coding to run on?

As for cells that have `0` values no comments are needed.

I've tried using `Range D8:F38` but it doesn't work, and instead returns the error

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets(1).Range("D8:F38").AddComment "This part needs to get reference from cells in other worksheet in same workbook"

End Sub
```

The expected result is that all the cells in `D8:F38` of `Sheet1` that are not valued `0` in its `=COUNTIFS` formula get comments (with the mini red triangle on top of it), with the contents of comments of each of the cells in `D8:F38` of `Sheet1` is referenced based on the text in cells `Sheet2` `=COUNTIFS` of cells `D8:F38`.

Example: The cell in `D9` has value of `2`, which is the result of a `=COUNTIFS` of cells in `Sheet2!C:C,fruits`, and the comment of the cell in `D9` has to be "apple oranges"

`fruits`         is just the second criteria in the `=COUNTIFS` formula of the cell `D9`

and

`apple`            is the word in the cell that `D9` `=COUNTIF` counted from `Sheet2`
`oranges`        is the word in the second cell that `D9` `=COUNTIF` counted from `Sheet2`

Comment: You might be better off assigning the text to a string and then using: `myRange.AddComment.Text myString`. Wihtout sample data, and expected output, it is difficult to guess how you will get the value of the string.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I do need the contents of comment in the cells to contain arrays of formula result from other cells. Is that possible?

Say for example: I want cell E16 to have a comment which contains the result of formulas of cell Q10 and cell S14

Q10 has formula of =SUM(3+4)
and 
S14 has formula of =SUM(5+7)

So I need the comment in cell E16 to write 7, 12

Is that possible to do with Excel VBA 2007?

Comment: Assign the `Value` of the cell to the string

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for your response. What if the contents of the cell comment, example, cell A1 to contain formulas that have {=index(....)}

Is it possible for VBA to output more than 1 results from array formula directly straight into the comment of cell A1?